# Launch osk.exe (Windows On Screen Keyboard) with different culture (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, localization

I am working on localizing a WinForms application that also uses elementhosts for WPF user controls inside Winforms. There is an on-screen keyboard available through osk.exe (it is a touch screen application) which serves well for English cultures.

However, I am localizing to French. Is there a way to launch osk with the French AZERTY layout besides writing my own keyboard application?

Comment: I think the OSK relies on the currently set keyboard language of the system, I'm not sure you can change this without changing the overall keyboard language

Comment: That's what I figured. Due to the embedded system the software is deployed on, I cannot change the system culture (which the keyboard relies on) from en-US to fr-FR.

Comment: And you can't expect the target computers to have a french layout I assume. Before rolling your own, there are already a couple of custom keyboards: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13596/Touchscreen-Keyboard-UserControl (Winforms), https://github.com/snmslavk/WPF-Keyboard-Control (WPF)

Comment: Thanks for linking those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to launch osk with the French AZERTY layout besides writing my own keyboard application?

No, I don't think so. At least there are no public API:s available to do this. Please refer to @Hans Passant's answer here for more information:

[LoadKeyboardLayout does not change the UI of On screen keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534700/loadkeyboardlayout-does-not-change-the-ui-of-on-screen-keyboard)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Looks like I will have to develop my own keyboard.